# how to get 1 item from a data binding in the controller?

Tags: sapui5

I have a table that is filled with data via data binding. And now in my controller i'm trying to loop over all items of the databinding. This is what i have so far but i can't get it to work.

```
colorRows : function(oTable) {
    var items = oTable.getBinding("items");
    var rowCount = items.length; //number of visible rows
    var currentRowContext;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        currentRowContext = items[i].getValue(); //this won't work
    }
}
```

so i need to get a value from the item with the index that matches i.

**edit:** i'm using sap.m.table

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use `sap.m.Table`.

```js
colorRows : function(oTable) {

    var sPath = oTable.getBinding("items").getPath(); //path to table's data
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel(); //model which is bound to the table
    //or var oModel = oTable.getModel(); if the model is bound directly to the table
    var aData = oModel.getProperty(sPath);//array of rows
    var rowCount = aData.length; 
    var currentRowContext;
    for (var i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        currentRowContext = aData[i]; 
    }
}
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/buledobuto/3/edit?html,output) is a working example.

Comment: is it possible that items[i] doesn't work? i get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCells' of undefined. there is data in items but items[i] results in undefined.

Comment: @freshrebel My bad, I have updated the answer. Sorry for misleading you.

Comment: now it's oModel.getProperty(sPath) that's not working. i get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. where aData is undefined. sPath is defined with the value /InvoiceSet.

Comment: @freshrebel it means you have to get your model, which is bound to the table, correctly. I don't know how exactly you defined the model - you didn't post that part of the code.

Comment: as you can see on this picture: https://ibb.co/eTPVT5, i think the model is recieved correctly. or am i seeing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As Keshet mentioned, it depends on the Table you are using. Here is an exapmle for the `sap.ui.table.Table`. First you get the Context of each Row and then you can access the Data that is saved on the Row (btw, there is no such thing as RowValue):

```
colorRows: function(oTable) {
 var aRows = oTable.getRows();
 var currentRowValue;
 for (var i = 0; i < aRows.length; i++) {
  var oRowContext = oTable.getContextByIndex(i);
  if (oRowContext) {
   var oRowObject = oRowContext.getObject();
   // or you can use the getProperty method
   var oSingleValue = oRowContext.getProperty("yourPropertyName");
  }
 }
}
```